# Why does this (grouped) mutate_at syntax work but summarise_at fails?

Tags: r, dplyr

Example data:

```
(tmp_df <-
    expand.grid(id = letters[1:3], y = 1:3))
#    id y
# 1  a 1
# 2  b 1
# 3  c 1
# 4  a 2
# 5  b 2
# 6  c 2
# 7  a 3
# 8  b 3
# 9  c 3
```

The following works:

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate_at(which(colnames(.) %in% c("y")),
              sum)
#   id        y
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 a         6
# 2 b         6
# 3 c         6
# 4 a         6
# 5 b         6
# 6 c         6
# 7 a         6
# 8 b         6
# 9 c         6
```

but the following throws the error `Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols`:

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise_at(which(colnames(.) %in% c("y")),
              sum)
```

Note that the following code snippets are alternative ways that successfully generate the expected result:

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(y),
                 sum)


tmp_df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise_at("y",
                 sum)
```

EDIT: following akrun's answer I should note that the dplyr version I am using is `dplyr_0.8.4`

Comment: Is this a bug? the helpfile for the `.vars` parameter explicitly says: `..., a numeric vector of column positions, ...` (I assume that this is what throws the error)

Comment: The accepted answer of the purported duplicate claims this was fixed but if it was then the problem got reintroduced at some later version so that it continues to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which(colnames(.) %in% c("y"))` returns you the index 2.

```
which(colnames(tmp_df) %in% c("y"))
#[1] 2
```

This is fine when you use `mutate_at`.

```
library(dplyr)
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate_at(2,sum)

#   id        y
#  <fct> <int>
#1 a         6
#2 b         6
#3 c         6
#4 a         6
#5 b         6
#6 c         6
#7 a         6
#8 b         6
#9 c         6
```

However, when you use `summarise_at` it does not count the grouped column. So you get an error when you do :

```
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_at(2,sum)
```

> Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols

What you actually needed here is

```
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_at(1,sum)

#   id        y
#* <fct> <int>
#1 a         6
#2 b         6
#3 c         6
```

However, it is not possible to dynamically change the position of column number that we want to use in `summarise_at` based on number of columns in `group_by` so a better option is to pass column names in `vars` instead of column number.

```
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate_at(vars('y'),sum)

#  id        y
#  <fct> <int>
#1 a         6
#2 b         6
#3 c         6
#4 a         6
#5 b         6
#6 c         6
#7 a         6
#8 b         6
#9 c         6

tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_at(vars('y'),sum)

#  id        y
#* <fct> <int>
#1 a         6
#2 b         6
#3 c         6
```

---

Good thing in `across` is that it behaves consistently for `mutate` as well as `summarise`.

```
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(across(2,sum))
```

> x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Location 2 doesn't exist.

```
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(2,sum))
```

> x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Location 2 doesn't exist.

Even with `across` it is better to use column name rather than position.

```
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(across(y,sum))
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(y,sum))
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the error message. Just as a note doing the following modification is more robust for my purposes: `summarise_at(colnames(.)[colnames(.) %in% 'y'], ...)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in `mutate_at` the column numbers include the grouping variables but in `summarize_at` they do not as both of the lines of code below work.  You could report this bug although given that the _at functions have been superseded by `across` I don't know whether it would be fixed.

```
tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate_at(2, sum)

tmp_df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize_at(1, sum)
```

This is further reinforced by the fact that if we swap the columns then they both work consistently since the grouping variable no longer affects the position of the y column.

```
tmp_df[2:1] %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate_at(1, sum)

tmp_df[2:1] %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize_at(1, sum)
```

Comment: that is a very clever diagnostic trick to swap the column ordering. And I think I will file a bug even though I don't think that it will be fixed either.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `contains`

```
library(dplyr)
tmp_df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(across(contains('y'), sum), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

The `_at`, `_all` suffix functions are deprecated and in place it is the `across` currently used

Comment: thanks. i guess it's time to update my dplyr version :|